# how to save paints into sdcard in android

Tags: android, android-emulator

here i need to save what ever i am dwan that paints and that background iamge  into sdcard. tried some method but here save only background image.paints are not saved.can u any one suggest me.

```
             public void save() {
               String filename5;
                          Date date = new Date(0);
                   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
                          filename5 =  sdf.format(date);


      try{
        mBitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.writingsapce);

             String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                OutputStream fOut = null;
                File file = new File(path, "/DCIM/"+filename5+".jpg");
                    fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                    fOut.flush();
                    fOut.close();

          MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }}
```

Comment: i think here you are not saving the new image you drawn on but just the original one. put your drawing methode so we can tell to you how to proceed ;-)

Answer (score -1):

try this snippet, i used it and it worked ;-)

```
try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
               mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
         } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
         }

            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            OutputStream fOut = null;
            File file1 = new File(path, "FitnessGirl"+Contador+".jpg");
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file1);

            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file1.getAbsolutePath(),file1.getName(),file1.getName());
```

Comment: hai here Contador means what?

Comment: contador is just a string value, a random one one  so that i could save many images within same folder without having to deal with exceptions

Comment: And be carreful on what your saving the original one or the one you paint on. Give me a moment to repoduce my code and i'll post it to you